# How do I center wells in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, centering

I am working on a simple homepage for my website but I want to get the well evenly spread out. I can align the left to the left and the right to the right but I cant seem to be able to get that middle well to always stay in the centre of the page. I have tried many things but they all don't work, have a look at [my site](http://clustermc.net/) to see what I want to do, the wells are under the image slider. This is the code I have done but and the CSS is the default bootstrap min css with a few tweaks for the colors.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 well" style="margin-left: 10px !important; width: 330px;
       margin-right: 10px; padding: 4px !important; min-height: 330px; ">
     <center>
       <img style="height: 135px;" src="img/ts.png" />
       <h3>TeamSpeak 3</h3>
           <br />
       <p>Chat with us on our TeamSpeak at: <br />
        <b><a href="ts3server://ts.clustermc.net">ts.clustermc.net</a></b>
        <br /> So, come have a wonderful conversation with us!</p>
     </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 well" style="margin-left: 10px !important; width: 330px;
       margin-right: 10px; padding: 4px !important; min-height: 330px; ">
     <center>
       <img style="height: 135px;" src="img/wool.png" />
       <h3>Cluster MC</h3>
       <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 7px; width: 200px;">
         <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 2.0%;">
         </div>
         <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 98.0%;">
         </div>
       </div>
       <p style="margin-top: -27px; color: white; font-weight: bold;">
           3 Online</p>
       <br />
       <p>Start collecting your ClusterCredits now at:<br />
         <b>play.clustermc.net</b></p>
    </center>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 well" style="margin-left: 10px !important; width: 330px;
      margin-right: 10px; padding: 4px !important; min-height: 330px; ">
   <center>
     <img style="height: 135px;" src="img/forums.png" />
     <h3>Community Forums</h3>
     <br />
     <p>Come and talk to some of our memers and staff at the forums! <br />
       <b><a href="http://clustermc.net/forums">www.clustermc.net/forums</a>
       </b>
       <br />We dont bite, we promise!</p>
   </center>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Sorry for the bad layout, im a beginner to coding and I want to learn :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the Updated code.I have nested a div with class well as it was getting overlapped when used with col-lg-4. Please check the below code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-4">
       <div class="well" style="height: 330px; width: 330px;">
          <center>
            <img style="height: 135px;" src="img/ts.png"/>
            <h3>TeamSpeak 3</h3>
            <br/>
            <p>Chat with us on our TeamSpeak at: <br/>
              <b><a href="ts3server://ts.clustermc.net">
                    ts.clustermc.net</a></b>
              <br/>
               So, come have a wonderful conversation with us!
            </p>
          </center>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
         <div class="well" style="height: 330px; width: 330px;">
           <center>
     <img style="height: 135px;" src="img/wool.png"/>
             <h3>Cluster MC</h3>
             <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 7px; width: 200px;">
             <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" 
                  style="width: 2.0%;"></div>
             <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" 
                  style="width: 98.0%;"></div>
          </div>
             <p style="margin-top: -27px; color: white; font-weight: bold;">
                3 Online
             </p>
             <br/>
             <p>Start collecting your ClusterCredits now at:<br/>
                <b>play.clustermc.net</b></p>
          </center>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="well" style="height: 330px; width: 330px;">
             <center>
               <img style="height: 135px;" src="img/forums.png"/>
               <h3>Community Forums</h3>
               <br/>   
               <p>Come and talk to some of our memers and staff at the forums
               <br/>
           <b><a href="http://clustermc.net/forums">
                     www.clustermc.net/forums</a>
               </b><br/>
                    We dont bite, we promise!</p>
             </center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This kinda works, it centres the wells perfectly but there is no padding to separate each box. so this is the original http://i.imgur.com/G2cO34O.png and this is what happened when i added the align and removed the padding http://i.imgur.com/5BORGJq.png so when i added the padding back in it gave me this http://i.imgur.com/w3z7mrI.png and when i just added it to the center it gave me this http://i.imgur.com/0XepazJ.png sorry if i'm confusing you but it is just bugging me atm. Also i wanted them all the same hieght, Thanks alot for the help though!

Comment: Ok got the point, try out using class="col-lg-3 well col-lg-offset-1" in all divs. And for getting in same height as you added before height and width is needed.Please let me know whether it helped you.

Comment: afaik align-attribute is not used in html5 anymore. imo you should use `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: @Rohitha Ok, I changed the div tags for the wells to this, "<div class="col-lg-3 well col-lg-offset-1" style="height: 330px; width: 330px;">" but as you can see it hasn't changed anything :/ http://clustermc.net/

Comment: @JonAugood: I have made few changes and updated the code above.Have a look

Comment: @Rohitha: Yes, it works perfectly, thank you so much for your help it was bugging me so much as I have OCD and if something is meant to be in the middle and it isn't I go crazy lol Thanks alot for your help it is much appreciated!

Comment: @JonAugood: If you like the answer, you can vote up too. It encourages the stackoverflow users. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your three 'well' divs are sitting in the middle of the page already?

As every thing is sitting in `<div class="container">` that is the bootstrap class used to center things on a page. As per http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#layouts.

Note: It looks like you're missing a final ending `</div>` for the `container` class

I'm not 100% sure what issue you are having. Maybe provide a screenshot of what you want to achieve?